# safari browser not displaying img src tag images

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is working fine on chrome and firefox but safari not showing normal images, its showing only background-images. Here is the link of my website - http://urcoach.staging.wpengine.com/
Normal img src=""/> this tag images are not showing

Need Help.

Comment: As I checked, it is showing images in safari as well, please share the link, which particular image is not showing over there.

Answer (score 0):

In

html:not(.mobile-true) #bottom-bar img, html:not(.mobile-true) #header img, html:not(.mobile-true) #main img:not(.animate-element,.ls-s-1)

Class: Opacity set to 0;

Comment: html:not(.mobile-true) #bottom-bar img, html:not(.mobile-true) #header img, html:not(.mobile-true) #main img:not(.animate-element,.ls-s-1)

Comment: Above class opacity set to 0.

Comment: Please update your answer instead of posting this in the comments.

Comment: CSS is written like for mobile you are hiding images, and it is creating issue,